# Help with a doubly linked circular list

Tags: java, linked-list, circular-list

How I can convert this doubly linked list into a doubly linked **circular** list?

```
public class DoublyLinkedList {
  private Link first; 

  private Link last; 

  public DoublyLinkedList() {
    first = null; 
    last = null;
  }

  public boolean isEmpty(){
    return first == null;
  }

  public void insertFirst(long dd){
    Link newLink = new Link(dd); 

    if (isEmpty()) 
      last = newLink; 
    else
      first.previous = newLink; 
    newLink.next = first; 
    first = newLink; 
  }

  public void insertLast(long dd){
    Link newLink = new Link(dd); 
    if (isEmpty()) 
      first = newLink; 
    else {
      last.next = newLink; 
      newLink.previous = last; 
    }
    last = newLink; 
  }

  public Link deleteFirst(){ 
    Link temp = first;
    if (first.next == null) 
      last = null; 
    else
      first.next.previous = null;
    first = first.next; 
    return temp;
  }

  public Link deleteLast(){ 
    Link temp = last;
    if (first.next == null)
      first = null; 
    else
      last.previous.next = null;
    last = last.previous; 
    return temp;
  }

  public boolean insertAfter(long key, long dd) { 
    Link current = first; 
    while (current.dData != key){
      current = current.next;
      if (current == null)
        return false; // cannot find it
    }
    Link newLink = new Link(dd); // make new link

    if (current == last) // if last link,
    {
      newLink.next = null; 
      last = newLink; 
    } else // not last link,
    {
      newLink.next = current.next; 

      current.next.previous = newLink;
    }
    newLink.previous = current; 
    current.next = newLink; 
    return true; // found it, insert
  }

  public Link deleteKey(long key){
    Link current = first; 
    while (current.dData != key)
    {
      current = current.next;
      if (current == null)
        return null; // cannot find it
    }
    if (current == first) // found it; first item?
      first = current.next; 
    else
      current.previous.next = current.next;

    if (current == last) // last item?
      last = current.previous; 
    else
      // not last
      current.next.previous = current.previous;
    return current; // return value
  }

  public void displayForward() {
    System.out.print("List (first to last): ");
    Link current = first; // start at beginning
    while (current != null) // until end of list,
    {
      current.displayLink();
      current = current.next; // move to next link
    }
    System.out.println("");
  }

  public void displayBackward() {
    System.out.print("List : ");
    Link current = last;
    while (current != null){
      current.displayLink();
      current = current.previous;
    }
    System.out.println("");
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    DoublyLinkedList theList = new DoublyLinkedList();

    theList.insertFirst(22);
    theList.insertFirst(44);
    theList.insertLast(33);
    theList.insertLast(55);

    theList.displayForward();
    theList.displayBackward();

    theList.deleteFirst();
    theList.deleteLast();
    theList.deleteKey(11);

    theList.displayForward();

    theList.insertAfter(22, 77); // insert 77 after 22
    theList.insertAfter(33, 88); // insert 88 after 33

    theList.displayForward();
  }

}

class Link {
  public long dData; // data item

  public Link next; // next link in list

  public Link previous; // previous link in list

  public Link(long d)
  {
    dData = d;
  }

  public void displayLink(){
    System.out.print(dData + " ");
  }

}
```

Thanks

Comment: See http://www.tinyurl.com/so-hints Post what you've tried so far.

Comment: 1) Please post code here instead of linking off-site. 2) What have you tried so far? Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: Circular list is pretty much the same the same thing except the first and last elements are also linked together. As other noted please describe what problem you have exactly, and show your current progress. Also pleas tag as homework if it is.

Answer (score 2):

The list, as is, doesn't provide a way to iterate over its elements. If it did, you could ask the list for an iterator and get the next element of the list from the iterator, until it reaches the last element. Making it circular would change the iterator behavior: it would go back to the first element once the last element is reached.

So, the answer is that to make it circular, you have to change the methods of the list so that the next link of the last one is the first one, an the previous link of the first one is the last one. But if you don't add other methods to the list, doing it won't change anything: the public behavior of the existing methods will stay the same once the list is made circular.